# Генерируем уникальные id на ходу SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sphinx

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT id, identy, status, header.value AS header, header.lang AS lang FROM merge.om_category
INNER JOIN merge.om_param AS header 
    ON (header.paramid = om_cat.id AND header.param = 'categoryname')
```

По его результату я получаю следующую виборку:

```
| id | identy  | status | header  | lang |
| 1  | product | 1      | ...     | ru   |
| 1  | product | 1      | ...     | ua   |
```

Уникальных значений в таблице om_param нету. Есть идеи как генерировать для конечного результата уникальные id? Можно ли слить id который имеется и дописать к нему язык, что бы получилось: `1_ru / 1_ua`

---

**UPDATE**
Перевернул все с ног на голову, спасибо  Etki.

Привел запрос к такому виду:

```
SELECT 
    concat(header.paramid,'_',header.lang) AS id,
    header.paramid,
    om_cat.identy,
    header.value AS header,
    keywords.value AS keywords
FROM om_param AS header
LEFT JOIN om_param AS keywords 
    ON (keywords.paramid = header.paramid 
        AND keywords.lang = header.lang
        AND keywords.param = 'category_keywords')
LEFT JOIN om_cat 
    ON (om_cat.id = header.paramid 
        AND om_cat.status = 1)
WHERE header.param = 'categoryname'
ORDER BY paramid;
```

Результат такой:

```
| id    | paramid | identy  | header  | keywords |
| 1_ru  | 1       | product | ...     | ...      |
| 1_ua  | 1       | product | ...     | ...      |
```

Sphinx, как я и подозревал кушает только int id.
Помогите разрулить это как то...

Comment: Пиши колонке тип int auto_increment, сама заполнится уникальными (для таблицы) значениями.

Comment: Можно (см. функцию CONCAT), но зачем?

Comment: @Etki, зачем CONCAT, если специально для этого есть GROUP_CONCAT?

Comment: @BOPOH автору не нужен GROUP_CONCAT, автору нужно уникально идентифицировать каждый результат.

Comment: @Etki, ой, мне показалось он языки хочет объединить в одной записи. Не подумал, что header для каждого языка свой будет

Comment: @автор, а зачем вам такой select? Если в выборке вас будет интересовать только один язык, то может и проблемы не будет?

Comment: Это запрос передастся в sphinx, который работает с уникальными записями. Дальнейший поиск будет идти по всем возможным языкам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эврика. MySQL поддерживает переменные. Объявляются так:

```
SET @row_number = 0;
```

Используются так:

```
SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num,
...
```

Хранятся в сессии, волноваться не о чем.